# Can Bluetooth headphones (Jabra BT 8010) be used as PC microphone

Tags: bluetooth, headphones, headset

I'm planning to buy a bluetooth headset (Jabra 8010) for chatting on PC. Can anyone confirm whether bluetooth headphones will work as microphone with PC. I just want to have wireless voice chat on my PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not paired that model with my computer but I have paired several others with my computer and they have all worked fine. Some models are difficult if you have them paired with more than one device and they are both in range. IE you have your phone and computer in range and they are both set up to work with the headset